# Connect C# MVC Source Code to localhost Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, model-view-controller, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I am starting a job at a new company and i'm supposed to start using a system developed  in .net core MVC by someone else.

I have a local copy of the database and a local copy of the code.
I can acces the SQL server DataBase and make my own SQL requests in SQL Server 2014, unfortunatly i cannot connect my Visual Studio code to my database and make everything work locally.

I tryed to load "Views\Home\Index.cshtml", the page starts to load at "localhost:45896" and after a few seconds i get the bellow error:

It appears the path is not properly written in the json file, but i am not sure how to write it any other way.

Or maybe something else.

Connection String:

> "ConnectionStrings": {
>       "DefaultConnection": "Server=/SQLExpress;Database=something_article;User
>   Id=admins;Password=Admin;",
>       "EntityFrameworkConnection": "data source=172.16.10.5;initial catalog=companyname_common;persist security info=True;user
>   id=admin;password=azerty;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework""
>   },

Thank you

Best regards
Rui

> An error occurred while starting the application. Win32Exception: Le
>   chemin d’accès spécifié n’est pas valide
>
> Unknown location SqlException: Une erreur liée au réseau ou spécifique
>   à l'instance s'est produite lors de l'établissement d'une connexion à
>   SQL Server. Le serveur est introuvable ou n'est pas accessible.
>   Vérifiez que le nom de l'instance est correct et que SQL Server est
>   configuré pour autoriser les connexions distantes. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à SQL
>   Server)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, string accessToken, bool
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)
>
> ```
> Win32Exception: Le chemin d’accès spécifié n’est pas valide
> ```
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Le chemin d’accès
>   spécifié n’est pas valide
>
> SqlException: Une erreur liée au réseau ou spécifique à l'instance
>   s'est produite lors de l'établissement d'une connexion à SQL Server.
>   Le serveur est introuvable ou n'est pas accessible. Vérifiez que le
>   nom de l'instance est correct et que SQL Server est configuré pour
>   autoriser les connexions distantes. (provider: Named Pipes Provider,
>   error: 40 - Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à SQL Server)
>
> ```
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> ```
>
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, string accessToken, bool
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate,
>   bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out
>   DbConnectionInternal connection)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource retry,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource retry,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,
>   out DbConnectionInternal connection)
>       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource
>   retry)
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource
>   retry)
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>       Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection()
>       Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection(DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func func)
>       Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection(DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Action action)
>       Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.Initialize()
>       Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage..ctor(string nameOrConnectionString, SqlServerStorageOptions options)
>       Hangfire.SqlServerStorageExtensions.UseSqlServerStorage(IGlobalConfiguration
>   configuration, string nameOrConnectionString, SqlServerStorageOptions
>   options)
>       SofedisWebsite.Startup.b__4_6(IGlobalConfiguration
>   m) in Startup.cs
>
> ```
>                 m.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
> ```
>
> new SqlServerStorageOptions()
>
> Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__10(IGlobalConfiguration
>   config)
>   Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.GetInitializedJobStorage(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactoryService(FactoryService
>   factoryService, ServiceProvider provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
>   singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider+<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__0(ServiceProvider
>   provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>   Hangfire.HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, BackgroundJobServerOptions options,
>   IEnumerable additionalProcesses, JobStorage
>   storage) SofedisWebsite.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
>   IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, FileServerProvider
>   fileServerprovider) in Startup.cs
>
> ```
>                 app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
> ```
>
> app)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>
> .NET Framework X64 v4.0.30319.42000    |
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 1.1.1    |    Microsoft Windows
>   10.0.10586    |   Need help?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look in your MVC application at a file called Web.config and locate the <connectionStrings> and make sure it points to your localdb?

Comment: My web.config file has no "ConnectionString" in it. :(

Comment: SOLVED, how to close?

Comment: Post your own answer to this question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

add connection string in web config

inside `configuration` tag

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connectionname" 
       connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=dbname;
       Integrated Security=True"; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and for reading that connection string use this: -

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionname"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Configure your Connection string TAG in the Web.config file.

User for example the site below:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/